# How can I use xonsh with edit-command-line in ZSH?

Tags: zsh, zsh-zle, xonsh

I'd like to open an editor buffer in ZSH using `edit-command-line` and have the contents of the buffer executed by xonsh.
Is it possible to do this cleanly?

The `edit-command-line` command in ZSH [lets you edit a command line using your editor](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6620/how-to-edit-command-line-in-full-screen-editor-in-zsh), which can then be executed by the ZSH interpreter.
It is especially useful for complicated, multi-line, commands.

[xonsh](https://xon.sh) is a Python-powered shell using Python as the scripting language.
I prefer Python to the ZSH language when writing complicated commands.

Extra-credit: It would be nice to tell the editor to use Python syntax highlighting, instead of ZSH.

Thanks!

Note: I can invoke xonsh in the following manner, but it's ugly and the syntax highlighting is wrong:

```
echo "
<python code>
" | xonsh
```